# WPF SelectedItem passed as a command parameter doesn't return value

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox x:Name="RootListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Ratings}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     

                         .... Some TextBoxes with Labels are here to fill the grid .....

                        <Button  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="Delete" 
                                 Command="{Binding ElementName=RootListView, Path=DataContext.DeleteRatingCommand}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=RootListView, Path=SelectedItem}">

                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Where `Ratings` in my view model is:

```
public ObservableCollection<RatingModel> Ratings;
```

And the `DeleteRatingCommand` is an `ICommand` object.

There is a whole collection of ratings displayed in this view (a grid containing information), every one has a delete button. When the button of the corresponding rating is pressed I want to send the rating object to the view model with the `SelectedItem` property. Although the binded method is called, there is nothing passed with the SelectedItem parameter, a `null` value specifically. How can I use `SelectedItem` properly in this case to send info to the view model about which rating is to be deleted? Are there any other possibilities? I'm not sure if this approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that clicking the button doesn't actually set the SelectedItem property.

Try changing the binding to the row context data.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
```

Comment: That's exectly what I came up with. You can even simplify it to `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`